# Sum ignoring strings in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am using Pandas to make a DataFrame. However some parts of the DataFrame contain a string. how can I ignore these strings in the sum when summing along the rows of the data frame?

```
df["sum"] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: What do you mean they contain a string? it is pretty hard to help you when we do not fully understand what you want to do. is there a string with digits, digits in string form, or just a string? show us a snippet of what the column looks like or if the column is't that big show us the whole thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to **ignore** the string values, then this will work:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce')
df['sum'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Without loop is possible use `df['sum']=df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x,errors='coerce')).sum(axis=1)`

Comment: apply() is nothing more than a glorified loop with some extra functionality and generally is as inefficient as a for loop.

Comment: Ya, I know. It is alterantive

Answer (score 7):

Use the `numeric_only` flag:

```py
df.sum(axis=1, numeric_only=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know about numeric_only. for some reason this didn't work in my case.